# Filter and map in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I'm doing "experiments" on a little example to understand the use of `filter()` and `map()` in JavaScript, and I have a question, based on the following code.

```
var numbers = [1, 4, 9, 25, 36, 49];

var roots = numbers.filter(function() {
  for (i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
        if (numbers[i] > 10) {
        var index = numbers.indexOf(numbers[i]);
      numbers.splice(index, 1);
    }
  }
  return numbers;
}).map(Math.sqrt);

console.log(numbers);
// -> [1, 4, 9]
console.log(roots);
// -> [1, 2, 3]
```

Why when I put `numbers[i] > 10` as a condition the output is correct, whereas if I put `numbers[i] < 10` the outcome is the following

```
console.log(numbers);
// -> [25, 36, 49]
console.log(roots);
// -> [1, 5, 7]
```

Where the numbers array is correct, but the roots array is *messed up*?

Comment: you are using `filter` in a wrong way... it should return `true` or `false` for every element in the array, indicating whether it should stay; in your code you always return `numbers`

Comment: You're right, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Your filter function is mutating the numbers array on which its operating; it should just return true or false depending on whether you want the item in the filtered results or not. For example

```
var roots = numbers.filter(function(n) {
        return n > 10;
  }).map(Math.sqrt);
```

In this case *numbers* is never changed, but *roots* contains all elements in numbers that are greater than 10.

[example fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/z7nvpgy7/)

Answer (score 0):

You are using `filter` but inside the callback, you are doing your own filter ... which I doubt is intentional. If you break down what your code is doing conversationally, it is basically "for each element in the array, iterate through the entire array (for loop) and in that loop iterate through the entire array again (`indexOf`)...". At this point you can probably determine something is wrong. Also `Array.splice` mutates the original array which is usually undesirable.

Here is an example of how you might want to use `filter` and `map`

```
var numbers = [1, 4, 9, 25, 36, 49];

// get numbers greater than 10
numbers.filter(n => n > 10)
// => [25, 36, 49]

// get numbers greater than 10 and take the square root of each number
numbers.filter(n => n > 10).map(Math.sqrt)
// => [5, 6, 7]
```

Note that these methods are chainable but never mutate the original array. This gives you a great amount of flexibility for performing array computations.

Answer (score 0):

This code is not doing what you think it's doing. It'll be acting very strangely because you're mutating the numbers array as you go along in the for loop.

The correct use of `filter` is to return true/false for each value, not return a new array. Return true to keep an element, false to remove it.

This is what you're after:

```
var numbers = [1, 4, 9, 25, 36, 49];

// notice "number" is taken as an argument
var roots = numbers.filter(function(number) {
  // return true to include this number, false to reject it
  return number < 10;
}).map(Math.sqrt);

console.log(numbers);
// NOTE: has not been changed
// -> [1, 4, 9, 25, 36, 49]
console.log(roots);
// -> [1, 2, 3]
```

To get an understanding of where your results are coming from, let's walk through each iteration of your code:

filter will run for each element of the array. the for loop will then go through and modify the array.

## for `number > 10`

### filter: value of 1

for the first 3 iterations of the for loop, nothing happens, then:

`i = 3`, so `numbers[3]` = 25. this passes the condition in your for loop, causing the `splice`, which will change numbers to `[1, 4, 9, 36, 49]`

this is where it gets weird #1

In the next iteration of the for loop, `i` will be 4, but the array has been changed. You may expect the value of 36 to be checked next, but because the array has been modified, and 36 is now in the place of 25, it will be missed. The next value to be checked is in fact 49. Similar reasoning shows that 49 will also be removed.

When the for loop is complete, you are left with `numbers = [1, 4, 9, 36]`

You then return `numbers`, which is truthy, which filter interprets as an instruction to keep `1` in the array.

### filter: values 4, and 9

The same reasoning can be followed to show that the values of 4 and 9 will remain in the numbers array, and 36 will be removed.

Now, because 25, 36, and 49 have been removed from the array, `filter` has completed its job, leaving `[1, 4, 9]` to be passed to `map` giving `[1, 2, 3]`.

### Result

It's actually provided the inverse of the correct answer.

## for `number < 10`

This is where it get *really* weird.

### filter: value of 1

the for loop will remove `1`, skip `4` (since it now takes the place of 1), remove `9` (which is in place of `4`), skip `25`, and keep the rest. This returns a value of `[4, 25, 36, 49]`, which is truthy, and intepreted as keeping `1`.

result of filter so far is `[1]`.

### filter: value of 25 (since it's now in the 2nd position in the array as 1 was removed)

the for loop will remove the 4, skip 25, and keep the rest. This returns a value of `[25, 36, 49]`, which is truthy, so interpreted as keeping `25`.

result of the filter so far is now `[1, 25]`

### filter: value of 49 (since it's now in the 3rd position in the array as 1, 4, and 9 have been removed)

the for loop will keep all of the values since they're all greater than 10, meaning that the return value will be `[25, 36, 49]`, which is truthy, which means that 49 is kept.

result of the filter will be `[1, 25, 49]`, mapped with `Math.sqrt` is `[1, 5, 7]`

### Result

0_o

## Conclusion

Never, ever modify an array as you're looping or using array functions on it.